# Is amplitude measured from the electric or magnetic fields of a wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

When you measure amplitude, does that refer to the electric portion of the electromagnetic field, or does it refer to the magnetic portion? Or is an average of the two?

Another question is, are the amplitudes of the electric and magnetic fields always the same, or can there be a difference? If so, what would happen if one of the fields is stronger than the other.

Comment: Surely the units --- volts per metre,  or tesla ---  make this clear?

Comment: an electric dipole antenna measures the electric field, a magnetic dipole antenna measures the magnetic field.

Comment: *are the amplitudes of the electric and magnetic fields always the same?* in Gaussian units they’re the same. In SI units they can’t even be compared!

Answer (score 0):

In Maxwell's electrodynamics the electric and magnetic fields are coupled, however, once you have found one of them you can easily find the other. When one talks about the amplitude of the electric or the magnetic field they are referring to that field specifically and not to an average between the two.

Now suppose that we are talking about a simple case, e.g. plane monochromatic radiation, where monochromatic refers to electromagnetic waves that are all of one frequency, this assumption makes the wave equation for the field in question easy to solve and has tremendous application, so it is not too much of a limitation. As a consequence of the coupling of the fields in the Maxwell equation we find that not only is such radiation transverse, but also that the magnitude of the $E,B$ fields are related. For example, if we know the magnitude of the electric field then we can find the magnitude of the magnetic field from:
$$ B={ \kappa\over\omega} E.$$
So, one cannot fix any arbitrary value for $E$ without having a predetermined corresponding value for $B$.
Where $\kappa$ is the magnitude of the propagation vector $\vec \kappa$ that is given by:
$$\vec \kappa=\kappa\mathbf{\hat u},$$
where $\mathbf{\hat u}$ is a *unit vector* that points in the direction of propagation of the electromagnetic radiation.